# What is the difference between optoisolator and motor driver?

Tags: relay, opto-isolator

Suppose we need to control power of a device (12v, 500mA).

I tried to use TLP281 board, which works, except that it inverts the output: device is powered  when there is no control signal.

For this reason, the TLP281 board is not useful in my project.

This is picture and schematics for TLP281 board:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I need an optoisolator board which works analogous to normally open mechanical relay: when
there is no signal, device must not be powered; and when
there is signal, device must be powered.

I consider to use ULN2003 arduino board instead of TLP281 board. Is ULN2003 supposed to be used as a relay at all?

*NOTE: workaround by inverting the control signal in microcontroller firmware is not permitted, as the device must not be powered when microcontroller is off*

Comment: Are you using a P-Channel MOSFET/PNP BJT? I am asking this since I had a look at the [TLP281 schematics](https://hacktronics.co.in/rs232485-usb-ttl-converters/4-channel-opto-isolation-module-high-and-low-expansion-board) and it does not seems to be an inverting unit. And could you post a schematic of the circuit you want to control? It would be much easier to see what it is needed in order to it to work according to your needs.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The board has additional discrete transistors to invert logic (signal on the input pins is reflected on output pins), stand alone TLP-281 sans discrete transistors may solve your problem....More curious about your load, thought current was limited to 50mA, you imply it works with 500mA?

Comment: ...nevermind....answer looks like the discrete transistor handles the current also. The opto by itself would not likely handle your load.

Comment: Do you know use cases of optocoupler (used in TLP281) vs field-effect transistor (used in ULN2003)? It looks like both allow to switch load on/off, but how to choose between them?